# jQuery effects lost after append html to another DIV,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div `inside` it has images carousel, and I'd like to append it to another DIV `outside`. However, I lost carousel on the new div `outside`.  How can I enable carousel for the appended div?

**online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PYQXa/**

```
<div class="inside">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <div class="outside">
          <!-- append content here -->
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
var $inside = $('.inside');
$inside.hide();
var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider').html();
$(appendcontent).appendTo($('.outside'));

// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 2000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);
```

it would be working fine if you remove

```
var $inside = $('.inside');
$inside.hide();
var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider').html();
$(appendcontent).appendTo($('.outside'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider').html();
```

The `html()` method returns the innerHTML of the jQuery element. In your example, it's a list of `<li>` nodes. Just replace the line with:

```
var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider');
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit : I've checked the fiddle again, you are appending only the 'li' into the new div. To have it work properly, you should use

```
$inside.find('.slider');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually, I will need to append some slide divs to other divs dynamically. So, I am wondering if it is possible to enable slider to work if I append them to another div. :-)

Comment: I've checked your fiddle again, and I have to update my answer. What was wrong is that you're taking the html of the slider, instead of the slider itself. Instead of having $inside.find('.slider').html() use instead $inside.find('.slider');

Answer (score 0):

You were adding the slider class content into the outside class but .. u need to add inside content on outside div otherwise all anim related to slider class will be vanish..

```
  var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider').html();
  var html = $inside.html();
  $(html).appendTo($('.outside'));
```

And the slider need to select like this

```
  var $slider = $('.outside .slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYQXa/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the appentcontent doesnt have the class "slider". You shold replace the line

```
$inside.find('.slider').html();
```

with

```
$inside.find('.slider').parent().html();
```